# Vuejs get arrays under array in dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have such data

[image: one]

## Issue

I cannot access `tubes` array under my `data`

## Code

`script`

```
data() {
    return {
        types: []
    }
},
methods: {
    handleChange (val) {
        axios.get(`/api/admin/getFromTubes/${val}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.types = res.data.data.tubes;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
```

`template`

```
<el-form-item label="Old Core">
    <el-select style="width: 100%;" filterable clearable v-model="form.old_core_id" placeholder="Select Old Core">
        <el-option
        v-for="cable in types"
        :key="cable.id"
        :label="cable.name"
        :value="cable.id">
            <span style="float: left">
                {{ cable.name }}
            </span>
        </el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-form-item>
```

## Question

How can I get my `tubes` array in template select(dropdown)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```js
handleChange (val) {
    axios.get(`/api/admin/getFromTubes/${val}`)
    .then(res => {
        this.types = res.data[0].tubes;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

or actually

```
this.types = res.data.data[0].tubes;
```